# Read multiple files and combine into one array

Tags: php

I am quite new to PHP so this could be somewhere already answered.  However, I just could not find similar answer to my problem so here it goes:

I have a template file called "frozen.txt"  This file contains the list of frozen item numbers.its conents look like

---

23476
23829
26974

---

I also have around 20 files representing daily sales data: "frozen-4-1.txt", "frozen-4-2.txt", "frozen-4-3.txt" etc.  Each txt file contains 3 columns separated by ";" .  The first column is exactly the same of "frozen.txt" .  The 2nd column representing inventory number in the unit of "Each" and the 3rd column representing inventory number in the unit of "Box".  For example, "frozen-4-1.txt" would look like:

---

23476;30;3
23829;100;10
26974;50;5

---

"frozen-4-2.txt" look like

---

23476; 20; 2
23829; 90; 9
26974; 40; 4

---

"frozen-4-3.txt" look like

---

23476; 10; 1
23829; 60; 6
26974; 20; 2

---

Now I want to creat two new files called "outputeach.dat" and "outputbox.dat" This files use "frozen.txt" as its first column, then use daily data txt file's 2nd column and 3rd column as their new columns, respectively.(separated by ";")  Therefore, "outputeach.dat" would look like:

---

23476;30;20;10
23829;100;90;60
26974:50;40;20

---

and "outputbox.dat" looks like

---

23476;3;2;1
23829;10;9;6
26974:5;4;2

---

Here is my code trying to achieve this, but I am stuck at the end of the program

---

```
<?php
include('path.php');
$space = "\r\n"; // For NewLine ...
$frzlist = array();
$readfrz = fopen("C:/purchase/dailydata/frozen.txt", "r");
while (!feof($readfrz)) {
$foo2 = fgets($readfrz);
$trufoo2 = trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $foo2 ) ); // get rid of new line in $foo2
$frzlist[] = $trufoo2; // read all the frozen item list into array $frzlist 
}
fclose($readfrz);
if ($handle = opendir(BASE_PATH)){
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
if ($file == "." || $file == ".."){}else
{
if(!strstr($file,"txt"))
{
continue; //Skip as file is not txt format
}
$s = explode("-",$file);
$prefix = $s[0];
$prefix1 = $s[1];
$prefix2 = $s[2];
//echo $prefix . " ";   // representing catogory
//echo $prefix1 . " ";  // representing month
//echo $prefix2 . " ";  // representing day
}

}
}
for($i=1 ; $i<32; $i++){  //loop through one month data
$days = $prefix1 . "-" . $i ;
$file1 = BASE_PATH . $prefix . "-" . $prefix1 . "-" . $i . ".txt" ;
//echo $file1 . "\n";
//echo $days . "\n";
if (file_exists($file1)) {
$fileopen1 = fopen($file1,"r"); 
while (!feof($fileopen1)) {
$foo = fgets($fileopen1);
$members1[] = $foo; // read all the  contents into array $members1
}
$outputfrzpri = array();
$outputfrzsec = array();
if($prefix = "frozen"){
foreach ($members1 as $x1){
$pieces1 = explode(";", $x1); 

CODE needs help here
CODE needs help here
}

}
}   
} 
?>
```

---

Your advices is much appreciated

Comment: indent your code maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It look like you are doing an text database. However, I think it could make your life much more easier to just use SQL as all you could possibly want to to with your information have, already been done in the past.

I am sure you have put a lot of effort to put that in place and it's not lost. The more you learn about PHP the more you will understand there is a lot of stuff already existing that simplify your life but I think the way you store this information is wrong.

SQL stand for Structured Query Language. There is a lot of resource on the internet and a large community around it.

Regards,

Comment: I know but I had this situation myself in the past and it create myself a lot of pain once i realized i was doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The reason I need this data on the same row is that I can import them into excel and draw a graph so I can visualize the decline in inventory number for each item as time elapses.  I think maybe I can do this by importing data into mysql table and use Excel's mysql module to direct import the table into excel.  However, I still need to creat a new column for each day in mysql table.  I will try to explore that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some advices:

1. Instead of `$frzlist[] = $trufoo2;` create associative array of arrays to fill with data:

   ```
   $frzlist[$trufoo2] = array(
        'each' => array(),
        'box' => array(),
   );
   ```
2. sometimes there are spaces around separating semicolon, you can get rid of them using `preg_split`:

   ```
   $pieces1 = preg_split("/\s*;\s*/", $x1);
   ```
3. Assign data to corresponding array:

   ```
   $key = $pieces1[0];
   $frzlist[$key]['each'][] = $pieces1[1];
   $frzlist[$key]['box'][] = $pieces1[2];
   ```
4. Iterate through main array creating line for every file

   ```
   foreach($frzlist as $key => $values){
       $eachline = $key .';'.implode(';', $values['each']);
       $boxline  = $key .';'.implode(';', $values['box']);
       //write to file
   }
   ```